# regex match combination of number,chars and nonchar with size of between 11-15

Tags: python, regex

i have a line of textoutput and want to catch the modelnumber which is between 11-15 digits long and looks like this: `UCSC-C240-M4L` or `UCSS-S3260-BASE`.
i tried `\b\w{11,15}\b` but this will fail because of the non word character "-". Do you have a proposal to fetch those strings? between 11-15 long, can contain numbers,words,and non-word-characters.

Comment: `[-\w]{11,15}` should work

Comment: nope, sadly it does not fetch if string is longer than 15

Comment: Can you add some valid and invalid matches in question. Also what's your regex platform?

Comment: i am trying with regex101.com and i am using pyhton

Comment: You said that the condition was 11-15 characters.

Comment: *can contain numbers,words,and non-word-characters* - so basically everything? That would simply be `\b.{11,15}\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex in python:

```
(?<!\S)(?=[\w-]{11,15}(?:\s|$))\w+(?:-\w+)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pluW8a/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\S)`: Negative Lookbehind to assert we don't have non-space character at previous position
- `(?=[\w-]{11,15}(?:\s|$))`:  Positive Lookahead to assert that we have only 11 to 15 of allowed characters ahead.
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*`: Match `-` separated string.